# Function not being called when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

So, as the title suggested. That's the problem. Below is my code, I would be very thankful for your kind assistance. Thank you!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><form action="Login.jsp" method="post" id="Logform">
            User: <input type="text" size="10" name="usr" id="user"><br>
            Password: <input type="password" size="10" name="pwd" id="pw"><br>
            <button type="button" onclick="mycheck()">  Login  </button>
        </form>
        <a href="Registration.html" target="MAINIFRAME"><button>Register</button></a>
        <center><a href="Advertise.jsp"><img src="Back.jpg" width="200"></a></center>
    </center>
    <script language="javascript">
        function mycheck()
        {
            var user = document.getElementById('user');
            var password = document.getElementById('pw');
            var MYform = document.getElementById('Logform');
            if (user.value == "" || user.value == null)
            {
                alert('Please enter username!');
                user.focus();
            }
            else if (password.value == "" || password.value == null)
            {
                alert('Please enter password!');
                password.focus();

            }
            else
            {
                MYform.submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

enter code here
```

Just some additional information:
Tried adding a semicolon after function, doesn't work.
Tried capitalizing onclick to onClick, doesn't work as well.

Comment: Works as expected for me. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bb7Tg/).

Comment: what exactly is not working?  The javascript code looks like it should work.  Capitalization on tags should not matter for the onclick.  Are you sure the problem is with the javascript?  Is the request to `Login.jsp` getting sent?  If so, what data is sent with the request?  I think @Kapil has a better approach - bind `onsubmit` and return an explicit true/false from your check method which should indicate whether or not to submit or not.

Comment: Note that control values are always strings, so `user.value == null` will always be false, even when `user.value == ''` is true.

Comment: @mrrogers I have no idea what is not working. I tried it on fiddle, it worked as planned, but it is not working. Yes, request to Login.jsp is being sent. Blank values are sent.

Answer (score 0):

try this ,...

the above one works fine for me where I remove action="Login.jsp" in Form Tag..

```
<button type="submit" onclick="mycheck();"></button>

Or

<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return mycheck();" />
```